# Why doesn't qdebug() produce any output when using static library?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, qt

I am trying to debug a multithreading program that uses static library function calls in another thread. It is extremely difficult for me to debug this, for some reason I am unable to get qDebug() from the static library. Also in the project file I do not see anything that would supress the debug messages.

Is there a reason why thsi would happen in Qt?

Does it have to do with multithreading or just static linking in general?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you expect the output to show up? "If no message handler has been installed, the message is printed to stderr. Under Windows, the message is sent to the console, if it is a console application; otherwise, it is sent to the debugger. This function does nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT was defined during compilation."

Comment: I expect it to show up in the stdout, I am using the application under linux. I have a qdebug() statement in the function before the library function, that one shows up. But when it enters the library code I see no output.

Comment: Nvm my bad, turns out my LD_LIBRARY_PATH was set to the wrong directory :P. This is stupid.